# Optimize MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql query taking 13 seconds to execute is there any way to reduce the execution time here is the explain

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS st.store_id as st_id, `st`.`store_id`
FROM `store` AS `st`
LEFT JOIN `coupon` AS `cp` ON st.store_id = cp.store_id
LEFT JOIN `deal` AS `dl` ON st.store_id = dl.store_id
LEFT JOIN `store_category_relations` AS `scr` ON st.store_id = scr.store_id
GROUP BY `st`.`store_id`;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | st    | index | NULL                  | PRIMARY               | 4       | NULL                |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cp    | ref   | store_id              | store_id              | 4       | sonicqa.st.store_id |    5 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dl    | ref   | idx_deal_fid_store_id | idx_deal_fid_store_id | 4       | sonicqa.st.store_id |  287 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | scr   | ref   | store_id              | store_id              | 4       | sonicqa.st.store_id |    2 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: store_id(s) : Are they indexed in all the tables?

Comment: If I am reading that SQL correctly it is just bringing back the store_id from the distinct first table, and being left joins the other tables will land up being irrelevant.

Comment: yes they are indexed in all tables

Comment: You need to show us the table and index definitions.  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

`Using index` in every atomic part of query... No temporary files, not iterating trough all rows...

You probably already have the fastest solution.

One question though: are you using InnoDB or another database engine?

Comment: this should be comments not answer.